# Problems debugging azure mobile service locally

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services, iis-express

I am working on azure mobile service, using c# and I would like to debug it locally using IISExpress 10 and localDB Sql DB.

Now I have a bizarre problem:

I have two versions of the same service (default downloaded from azure portal) and default modified. Both are working fine in the cloud, however version the modified version when started locally, give me the following message:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>
> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Web.config and applicationhost.config files are nearly identical (differences are ports, names of assembly and localdb file). The biggest difference between the projects in the number of controllers and DB schema.

WebApiConfig.Register is actually being executed, but then nothing happens.

**Any idea how I can troubleshoot this issue any further?**

Update: Remote debugger works fine (very slow thought), the older version starts, can be debugged and accessed via web client. New version still does not start properly. What i did in the last iterations of troubleshooting: synced all config and project files, so no settings come in between, commented out all advanced code. Nothing has helped me so far to start the new version of my service past 403 message which I believe is not correct - it has nothing to do with 403, something else happens, maybe localdb initialization, dont know, will try to work with remote debugging for now. The problem is bizarre and strange, so If you can point me in the direction of the possible troubleshooting. Like what else can I check to identify the source.

Comment: You haven't given any indication of troubleshooting or provided any code.  So I can only guess.  1) Your table controllers are not listed, 2) You need to run your code through a debugger to see what is happening (you can do this with Visual Studio when developing locally or remotely).

Comment: Without more information, it's impossible to tell what is happening.

Comment: What kind of information I can provide, have two projects one works, the other not and they are basically identical. And both projects work in the cloud.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by gradually copying files from broken project into working one. Now I have a working project with all the code from broken one and it still works. The other project still does not. Project files seems to be the same.